# Marketing Cloud Connect - Connecting to mc.test.exacttarget (test / production support) via Authenticated App

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect

We have an account on mc.test.exacttarget.com (production support / test account).

We are working through the install instructions of Marketing Cloud Connect.

We have reached the step of supplying the API Username/Password.

My question is if this is the scenario where we need to be updating the API-URL in the login screen under the Marketing Cloud tab?

[image]

The issue is that it is not recognizing my Username/Password. I think this has to do with the login box pointing to authentication for production Marketing Cloud accounts.

When I attempt to update the API-URL to be https://webservice.test.exacttarget.com/Authentication/Auth.svc I get an error that it is an unauthorized endpoint.

Are there specific instructions for going down the Authenticated App path to connect the clouds when we are dealing with a test account? I dont want to revise too many settings via guesswork unless I can confirm this. Hoping someone else has dealt with the production support accounts and connection as well.

[image]
[image]

Thanks so much!

======

## UPDATED

I did go ahead and attempt to add the additional remote site within Sales Cloud. It appears this is cascading to various other endpoints as well. The connection appears to clear past the first 'remote site' and throws an error on the next step (all of which I imagine are part of the auth process taking place in the background). I now need to add https://rest.test.exacttarget.com/rest/beta/organization/user/@me/.

[image]

Comment: There is a help article sort of buried away. I found a thread regarding Production Support accounts here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000Zho3AAC.

That pointed me to this help article hosted by Exact Target:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/marketing_cloud_sandbox_support/

Comment: Here are the IP whitelistings and remote sites suggested

Enter 66.231.94.29 in the Start IP address.
Enter 66.231.94.29 in the End IP address.
Enter 66.231.94.29 in the Start IP address.
Enter 66.231.94.247 in the End IP address.
Enter `66.231.94.250 in the Start IP address.
Enter 66.231.94.252 in the End IP address.

As well as.....

Remote Site Name Remote Site URL
Auth_ProductSupport https://webservice.test.exacttarget.com
IMH_ProdSupport https://imh.test.exacttarget.com
MC_ProdSupport https://mc.test.exacttarget.com
REST_ProdSupport https://rest.test.exacttarget.com

Answer (score 0):

The API URL does indeed need edited to point to **https://webservice.test.exacttarget.com/Authentication/Auth.svc**.

*WARNING*: However. As of today (August 29, 2016) Marketing Cloud appears to have issues in a sandbox account (mc.test.exacttarget.com) when you attempt to use Authenticated App to 'CONNECT ACCOUNT' to your Sales cloud instance.

We receive a generic error. We have added the various IPs and Remote Sites that were required for v5 of the integration to work with sandbox accounts without success.

Our ticket with Marketing Cloud support resulted in a conclusion that **Marketing Cloud Sandbox Accounts no longer support integration with Sales Cloud.** --- Because Authenticated APP is required and it is not built to support that.

We are instructed to look at provisioning a production account as a sandbox.

I hope this helps anyone looking into the idea of using SANDBOX accounts (or working with a client already implemented in a Sandbox for testing purposes).